# How can i add a Person and Group control to Workflow Initiation From in SharePoint Designer 2010 x64

Tags: sharepoint-designer, people-picker, initiation-form

For some reason there is no Person and Group type in Add Field dialog on workflow's Initiation Form creation process in SharePoint Designer 2010.[image]

I assume it should be there as it shown in screenshot in [this tread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/d75fab61-f9b9-4b71-8568-0a4b85cd6127) but it's not. Does anyone know how can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this issue you need to navigate to site collection's Site Settings page, click 'Site collection features' link, then activate a feature called "Workflows".

Comment: If you solved the problem stated in your original question, you should mark this answer as accepted answer to help future visitors.